# Why did I get that the relation between distance covered and number of steps for random motion is quadratic although it should be linear?

Tags: python, proof, computation-theory

I was working on a problem, where I was proving that for someone taking random-sized steps in 2-D, the relation between the total distance covered and the square root of the number of steps is linear. However, I ended up proving that it varies linearly with the number of steps and varies as a quadratic function with the square root of the number of steps.

What is wrong with my code? Am I misunderstanding something?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math
#defining the initial values of the variables to start at 0 and the number of iterations (n) to be 1000.
x = 0
y = 0
n = 1000
listx = []
listy = []
listr= []
listn = []
r = 0

#starting a for loop with n iterations.
for i in range (0, n+1):
  #Appending all x values to listx
  listx.append(x)

  #Appending all y values to listy
  listy.append(y)

  #Generating random coordinates in both dimensions in the range between -1 and 1 for both x and y values.
  x -= (random.random()-0.5)*2 
  y -= (random.random()-0.5)*2 

  #Defining r to be the distance covered each step using the Pythagorean theorem and appending the total distance covered after each step to listr
  r += math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
  listr.append(r)

for i in range(0, n+1):
  listn.append(math.sqrt(i))

#Plotting the random steps taken using each given value of x and y. 
plt.plot(listx, listy)
plt.xlabel("steps in the x-axis")
plt.ylabel("steps in the y-axis")
plt.title("Visualization of the random steps taken")
plt.show()

#Plotting the relation between the total distance covered and the number of iteration. 
plt.plot(listn, listr)
plt.xlabel("square root of n")
plt.ylabel("distance")
plt.title("Distance covered vs the number of iteration")
plt.show()
```

I have tried to prove the linear relation and correlate my code with the mathematical expression, and they are identical for me. I don't know what is wrong exactly.

Comment: In what sense does this code prove anything?

Comment: When you say "total distance covered," do you mean the distance from `0, 0`, or the distance moved? If it's the first option, then this code is wrong, because `x =` should be `x +=`, `y =` should be `y +=`, and `r +=` should be `r =`.  If it's the second option, then I'd expect the relation between number of steps and distance to be linear, because each step can only add to the distance, and each step is on average equal size.

Comment: It's really unclear what your code has to do with the problem stated.  You're taking random single steps, and then calculating the length of that step.  You want the distance from the origin to the sum of all the steps you've taken so far

Comment: @NickODell My initial understanding is the second option but maybe the textbook wants me to measure the distance from the origin. I tried rewriting it to measure the distance from the origin, but it didn't work. Could you elaborate more on what can I do?

Comment: @FrankYellin It isn't really a problem but more of an activity to plot the relation. I'm just trying to proof it for myself.

Comment: @BelalBahaa Can you update the question with the new code?

Comment: @NickODell I just updated it like you mentioned above to measure the distance from the origin. However, it still seems to be wrong, and I also don't really see why would the relation be linear then.

Comment: @BelalBahaa I don't see your edit.

Comment: @NickODell I edited the code. I realized that the code is actually generating random coordinates not steps. So, I added a (-=) instead to calculate the size of the step. However, it is still incorrect. I also tried your suggestion and tried measuring from the origin, but I got wrong answers as well.

Comment: You're still using `r +=`. That's calculating the sum of all distances at each step from the origin. I suggest `r =` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252555/discussion-between-belal-bahaa-and-nick-odell).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).